# Auto Increment ID stuck at 10 when ID get 2 digit value

Tags: c#, xml

In an xml file, I insert values to it. I give the Id numbers automatically for each Flight entered. The values are added into the Id 10 object automatically after ID gets 2 digit value. How can i solve this ?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(inputpath);
            var userElements = xDoc.Descendants("Flight").ToList();
            string lastID = userElements.Select(x => (x.Attribute("ID").Value))
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                  .First()
                  .ToString();
            int lastID_dbl = Int32.Parse(lastID);
```

---

```
  <Flight ID="10" Description="10test" Date="9/10/2022 12:00:00 AM">
    <Instructor Num="10">
      <Name>10test</Name>
      <Surname>10test</Surname>
      <Rank>10test</Rank>
    </Instructor>
    <Instructor Num="11">
      <Name>11test</Name>
      <Surname>11test</Surname>
      <Rank>11test</Rank>
    </Instructor>
  </Flight>
  <Flight ID="10" Description="11test" Date="9/10/2022 12:00:00 AM" />
```

Comment: There's shouldn't be more than one 'ID="10"', try changing "ID" attribute value on every <Flight> namescape

Comment: and for further questions remember to provide whole code or at least enough information ex. full function

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve], but when you do `userElements.Select(x => (x.Attribute("ID").Value)).OrderByDescending(x => x)` you are sorting, in reverse, strings by lexical order rather than integers by value, so `"9"` will come before `"10"`, not after.  You probably want something like `int? lastId = userElements.Max(x => (int?)x.Attribute("ID"));`  The result will be null if there were no flight elements found.

Comment: You are not sorting the elements, just the value of the attributes.  XElement highest = userElements.Elements()OrderByDescending.(x => (int)x.Attribute("ID")).FirstOrDefault();  To get value : int lastID_dbl = userElements.Elements()OrderByDescending.(x => (int)x.Attribute("ID")).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng OrderByDescending and x attribute give error

Comment: @dbc i tried your solution and it goes after 10 like 20 30 40.......

Comment: @mert then please edit your question to share a [mcve].  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
var file = XDocument.Load(inputpath);    
int lastID_dbl = file.Descendants("Flight")
                               .OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("ID").Value))
                               .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("ID").Value))
                               .FirstOrDefault() + 1;
```